# table width too large with collapse and bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, width, border

I'm using bootstrap 3 and having some collapse tables. The problem is that when the table is visible (collapse in), the table is larger than content (you can see it with browser inspections tools), so there is a new unwanted border.

If I remove either collapse class or bootstrap import the problem disappear, so it must be something added by bootstrap, but I don't know how to override it correctly.

Anybody have an idea to remove that border ? If you know how to hide it, even if the width stay bigger it's not a problem for my actual usage.

Here's my code :

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/6899/

```css
th,
td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="collapse_FR24" class="collapse in" style="">
  <tr>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1995</td>
    <td>26589.3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1996</td>
    <td>26756.3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1997</td>
    <td>26223</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally manage to do it, I add a div around my table and make the collapse on the div rather than the table :

```css
th,
td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="collapse_FR24" class="collapse in">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1995</td>
      <td>26589.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1996</td>
      <td>26756.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1997</td>
      <td>26223</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```